# jump if findelementbypartialtext=false

Tags: vba, selenium

how do I make it so that if there is no link to click on because it is not found it continues to jump?

```
if GC.FindElementByPartialLinkText("CANTFINDTHIS") =false
MsgBox ("false")
else
MsgBox ("true")
end if
```

i get
`Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`

somehow there is a true false in the boolean but i haven't figured out how to use it yet

```
Function FindElementByPartialLinkText(partiallinktext As String, [timeout As Long = -1], [raise As Boolean = True])
```

Comment: good idea, but this doesn't work

Comment: Try to 1) check you added selenium VBA reference in VBE `tools -> references -> 'Selenium Type Library'`, 2) check type of GC `debug.print TypeName(GC)`

Comment: 1) is checked
2) typeName of GC is ChromeDriver